# Access Table from Code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code:

```
for(int u = 0; u < 3; u++)
{
   TableRow row = new TableRow();
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        cell.ID = "test"+i;
        cell.Text = "Cell" + i + "-" +u;
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
   }

   tabAntraege.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

So now I have an ASP.NET table like so:

```
| Cell0-0 | Cell1-0 | Cell2-0 |
| Cell0-1 | Cell1-1 | Cell2-1 |
| Cell0-2 | Cell1-2 | Cell2-2 |
```

Now I want to change the `Text` in cell "Cell0-0".

So I wrote this code:

```
TableRow t1 = tabAntraege.Rows[0];
TableCell t2 = t1.Cells[0];
t2.Text = "new Text"
```

When I try to use my code I get the following error:

> system.argumentoutofrangeexception specified argument was out of the range of valid values

Somebody got an idea?

Here the code from the `Button` event:

```
    protected void test(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(tabAntraege.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            TableRow t1= tabAntraege.Rows[0];
            TableCell t2 = t1.Cells[0];
            t2.Text = "new Text";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming from what you've posted that you are declaring the table in the markup, but filling it with `TableRow` and `TableCell` instances during the `Load` event.

You'll have to re-create the rows that you've put in the table every time you post back, as well as any controls you've put in the table cells.

Doing that in the `Page_Init` handler will allow their content and attributes (such as background color, etc.)  to be persisted across postbacks.

List controls (such as the `DataGrid`, `DataList`, and `GridView`) will do this automatically if they're databound, but an ordinary `Table` will not.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for the information!
But can i do something to avoid this? 
I mean.. that the button just triggers a event not a postback?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. If you want to avoid the appearance of a postback, you can use an `UpdatePanel`, but you'd probably still need to re-create the table contents in the code-behind. But if you're new to web programming, that's what I'd recommend. An Ajax call is also a possibility, but you wouldn't be able to access your table control at all on the server in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, but can you try the following:

```
tabAntraege.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "new Text";
```

Can you check in your code if the `tabAntraege` has rows first.

Comment: So tabAntraege is not null, tabAntraege.Rows.Count is greater than 0. Is this correct?

Comment: cheked it with if(tabAntraege.Rows.Count != 0){}

Comment: ah okay.. i checked it. tabAntraege.Rows.Count = 0  but why?

Comment: After the second for cycle tabAntraege.Rows.Count equals how much?

Comment: Its "0". So there are no Rows. But how can there be no rows if the table is filled and i see it on the screen?

Comment: What are you doing between the end of the second for cycle and the if(tabAntraege.Rows.Count > 0) row?

Comment: I press one button. Not i tried to do it all in one and it worked fine.. But why is the Table empty when I press a button?

Comment: Can you post the code of the button event? Where you get the table and how?

Comment: Are you loading the data into the table on some event. If so may be there is a PostBack after that and the table is cleared. Can you check for this?

Comment: there is another button for filling it. But i saw now, when i prss the button for changin the text the whole page refreshes.. can this be the problem?

Comment: Yes. When the page is refreshed the table is cleared of the content. You can add the filling in the Page_Load and check for IsPostBack.

Comment: One way is to add the code (or method) which fills the table in the Page_Load method of the page.

Comment: the thing is this method should not be used on "Page_Load" the user first has to select a few things then he can press this button..